# Magento Get all Product Collection in Admin Controller by Store id's

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I have added 2 stores into magento admin Canada and Australia 
now I want to get store wise product collection
Currently getting Product collection in mangeto **admin controller** using

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

using this I am getting all the products i tried this

```
$collection->setStoreId(2); // here 2 is the store id
```

but not much luck :(
is there I am missing something? I extended class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this -

**Filter Current Store Products -**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

For more please follow this -
[Product Collection in Magento](http://magentostriker.blogspot.in/2012/04/product-collection.html)

-

Thanks

Comment: Not only thanks ya. Mark it as accepted answer. :D
By the way your welcome. :)

Comment: Another way to filter products that are not visible (visibility set to Not Visible) is $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('gt'=> 1)).

Answer (score 3):

**get active store id** :- `$storeId =Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();`

you can use below code may be help you

```
$collection->setStoreId($storeId)

$collection->addStoreFilter($storeId)
```